# Spring + xstream: fields not shown in the correct order

Tags: spring, rest, xstream

So I'm using XStream to create my xml rest response and I'm having a bit of trouble with the field order. It does not match with the defined order in the converted class, nor with the opposite declaration order as mentioned as one of the issues with the 1.2.2 release (I'm using the 1.4.4 release).

So if my class looked like:

```
person:
    name
    age
    gender
```

the order in the output is

```
age gender name
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to order these?
Most posts I can find refer to the order of setters, but I'm just using a Person constructor and letting spring + XStream handle the conversion automatically.

edit:
config portion:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"/>

    </map>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />

                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                            <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
                            <property name="supportedClasses">
                                <list>
                                    <value>com.jackdans.model.InterestingPeople</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [FAQ](http://xstream.codehaus.org/faq.html#Serialization_sort_fields)...

```
SortableFieldKeySorter sorter = new SortableFieldKeySorter();
sorter.registerFieldOrder(Person.class, new String[] { "name", "age", "gender" });
xstream = new XStream(new Sun14ReflectionProvider(new FieldDictionary(sorter)));
```

If you wanting to integrate this with Spring, that's another matter. You would probably have to create a XStream factory or provide a custom implementation that did something akin to the code above.

Comment: I checked that portion, but as mentioned I am not creating an xstream instance. I am letting spring handling the conversion for me. All I did was add the required maven dependencies and add a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver (as shown at: http://pfelitti87.blogspot.be/2012/07/rest-services-with-spring-3-xml-json.html

Comment: I did just try out adding the FieldKeySorter interface and creating that map there. But it does not seem to be invoked whilst the specs do imply that it gets called automatically. Any advice?

Comment: I/We would need to see the relevant parts of your Spring config.

Comment: I've added the relevant portion.